# solr product promotions

Tags: solr

Is it possible to have product promotions in SOLR. For example - I want to boost all the products which belongs to category:"running shoes" and price: [0 TO 100]

So if is search shoes, then the products which belongs to the category:"running shoes" and price: [0 TO 100], should appear higher in the search result.

Answer (score 3):

Check e.g. [Boost Score](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) OR If you are using Dismax parser check for parameter [Boost Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29)

For your condition you can try `bq=(category:"running shoes" AND price: [0 TO 100])^2.0`